# char instead of std::atomic_flag or std::atminc_bool

Tags: c++

I am wondering if one can use

```
char Flag;
```

instead of

```
std::atomic_flag Flag;
```

I know that C++ fundamental types, generally speaking, are not atomic/thread safe (that's why `std::atomic` exists), but also I know that size of `char` is always 1 byte. And I cannot imagine situation in which read/write of single byte is not thread safe.

Also I cannot find anything about thread safefy of char variable.

Consider following example (Win32, Visual Studio 2015, Release, optimisation disabled):

```
// Can be any integral type
using mytype_t = unsigned char;

#define VAL1 static_cast<mytype_t>(0x5555555555555555ULL)
#define VAL2 static_cast<mytype_t>(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAULL)

#define CYCLES (50 * 1000 * 1000)

void runtest_mytype()
{
    //  Just to stop checking thread
    std::atomic_bool Stop = false;

    const auto Started = ::GetTickCount64();

    auto Val = VAL1;

    std::thread threadCheck([&]()
    {
        //  Checking values
        while (!Stop)
        {
            const auto Val_ = Val;
            if (VAL1 != Val_ && VAL2 != Val_)
                std::cout << "Error! " << std::to_string(Val_) << std::endl;
        }
    });

    std::thread thread1([&]()
    {
        for (auto I = 0; I < CYCLES; ++I)
            Val = VAL1;
    });

    std::thread thread2([&]()
    {
        for (auto I = 0; I < CYCLES; ++I)
            Val = VAL2;
    });

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    std::cout << "mytype: finished in " << std::to_string(::GetTickCount64() - Started) << " ms" << std::endl;

    Stop = true;
    threadCheck.join();
}

void runtest_atomic_flag()
{
    std::atomic_flag Flag;

    const auto Started = ::GetTickCount64();

    std::thread thread1([&]()
    {
        for (auto I = 0; I < CYCLES; ++I)
            auto Val_ = Flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire);
    });

    std::thread thread2([&]()
    {
        for (auto I = 0; I < CYCLES; ++I)
            Flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    });

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    std::cout << "atomic_flag: finished in " << std::to_string(::GetTickCount64() - Started) << " ms" << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    runtest_mytype();
    runtest_atomic_flag();

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs something like this (during several tests, the values did not change much):

```
mytype: finished in 312 ms
atomic_flag: finished in 1669 ms
```

So, `char` instead of `atomic_flag`, works significantly faster, which can play role in some cases.

But I am far from the idea that `std::atomiс_flag` was invented in vain.

Please, help me figure it out. At least, can I use `char`, when I use only Windows, only Visual Studio, and I don't have to think about compatibility?

Comment: *"optimisation disabled"* - Benching without optimization is pointless, especially in C++. What do you get if you enable optimization?

Comment: In this very simple test, optimization just eliminates cycles (because result is not used anywhere), so the result can not be taken into account. But, as @Jarod42 pointed below, my case is sompletely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes of atomic variables are also visible in other thread.

When using `char`, the modification might be not visible to other threads (that's why some people wrongly use `volatile` for synchronization).

Btw, modifying `char` concurrently without synchronization is UB.

Comment: Uh. You are completely right. I forgot that, even if single r/w operation is atomic, "read AND write" will not be atomic. My bad. Sorry for dumb question.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but what does UB mean?

Comment: @4xy: UB stands for **U**ndefined **B**ehavior.